# i3 turning on numlock

Tags: i3, numlock

I hate numlock.  I have 'enable numlock on boot' disabled in BIOS.  When I boot to windows, numlock is not on.  When I boot into Linux and sit at the login screen, numlock is not on.  When I enter my password and enter i3, numlock is on.  Case-insensitive grep for 'num' in .i3/config is empty.  What's going on?

Comment: What distribution are you running? What display manager are you logging into? If you select a different session type, is numlock turned on?

Comment: I am so interested to know what you use scoll lock for if you have a full size keyboard, since there are dedicated arrow keys, home/del/pageup/page down keys right next to it. I wish scroll lock never existed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you did not specify much details about your system there's not much to go on.

I would recommend to download "numlockx", since I don't know which distro you are using I can't tell you how, but you should know how to install applications...

When numlockx is installed, just type this into your i3config:
`exec_always --no-startup-id numlockx off`

I hope that solved your issue.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did a month ago when I had this issue, and it solved it.

Comment: Thank you! I had the exact opposite problem (needing to enable numlock each time) and it solved it as well